# How can one generate a vanity Bitcoin address with both a given prefix and suffix?

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen

I want generate a unique Bitcoin address with `vanitygen` that has both a given prefix and a given suffix: 
  1Bit******************Bit

How would I be able to achieve that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need this for? This could be used maliciously by an attacker trying to replace an address with their own address that has the same first and last few characters, which I hope is not why you're trying to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Vanitygen has a regex option, for generating addresses that match an arbitrary regular expression.  I think that

`vanitygen -r '^1Bit.*Bit$'`

would work.

Note that it will not be able to estimate the expected time that would be required.